How to slide mutiple images left continuously?
I use ffmpeg to slide images from left to center as below:
#slide 1st image from right to center
#countdown 10 seconds
#slide 1st image from center to left and in the same time
#slide 2nd image from right to center
#countdown 10 seconds
#...

ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -loop 1 -i input.png -filter_complex "split=2[bg][slider];[bg]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[bg];[bg][slider]overlay=x='max(W-w*t,0)':y=0" -t 10 -y output.mp4

There is black background between two images, I want to the preious page keep slide from center to left and next page slide fron right to center, what can I do?


try this: ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 4 -i in1.png -loop 1 -t 4 -i in2.png -loop 1 -t 4 -i in3.png -filter_complex " [0][1]xfade=duration=2:offset=2:transition=slideleft[v]; [v][2]xfade=duration=2:offset=4:transition=slideleft " output.mp4

the output.mp4 just black...

try next: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in1.png -loop 1 -i in2.png -filter_complex " [0]split=2[bg][v]; [bg]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[bg]; [bg][v]overlay=x='if(lt(t,10),max(W-w*t,0),max(0-w*(t-10),0-W))'[bg]; [bg][1]overlay=x='if(between(t,10,20),max(W-w*(t-10),0),max(0-w*(t-20),0-W))' " -t 22 output.mp4

Great!  Answer, please! By the way, I used ffmpeg -i %1.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile='/WINDOWS/Fonts/Arial.ttf':text='%%{eif\:%2-t\:d}':fontcolor=red:fontsize=24:x=w-tw-10:y=th-10:box=1:boxcolor=orange@0.4:boxborderw=10:enable='between(t,0,%2)'" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -y %1-countdown.mp4 to add countdown, how can I merge this to your answer?

just add to chain: ... ,0-W))', drawtext=..." -c:a copy ...

Well, I got it.Thanks you very much! what can I do for multiple images?

Script. For multiple images will be better to use xfade. If use overlay for it, you may run out of RAM.

Can you give me a sample?

some python script, partly adapted:
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

LST=[]
DIR="/mnt/public/upload/jpgs+audio/"
LSD=os.listdir(DIR)
LSD.sort()
for f in LSD:
  if (f.endswith(".jpg")):
    print(f)
    LST.append(f)

FLV=''
OFS=0        #start
XFO=10       #countdown in seconds
OFE=OFS+XFO  #end
CNT=0        #counter

INP=[]
f=DIR+LST[0]
INP.append(f' -loop 1 -i "{f}"')
PDV='[v0]'
FLT=f"""
[0]split=2[bg][v];
[bg]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[bg];
[bg][v]overlay=x='if(lt(t,{OFE}),max(W-w*t,0),max(0-w*(t-{OFE}),0-W))'{PDV};
"""
OFS+=XFO
OFE=OFS+XFO

for CNT in range(1, len(LST)):
  FLV+=f'{PDV}'
  PDV=f'[v{CNT}]'
  FLV+=f"""[{CNT}]overlay=x='if(between(t,{OFS},{OFE}),max(W-w*(t-{OFS}),0),max(0-w*(t-{OFE}),0-W))'{PDV};
"""
  f=DIR+LST[CNT]
  INP.append(f' -loop 1 -i "{f}"')
  OFS+=XFO
  OFE=OFS+XFO

OFS+=2
s='ffmpeg'
for t in INP:
  s=s+t
s=s+f' -filter_complex "{FLT}{FLV}" -map {PDV} -t {OFS} output.mp4 -y'
print(s)
os.system(s)
os.system(f'mpv output.mp4')


When I run your script, I got error Cannot load nvcuda.dll, what can I do? I deleted -c:v h264_nvenc, now it is ok!

Same question, how add countodown 10 to every page?

Can you add [0]split=2[bg][v]; [bg]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[bg]; [bg][v]overlay=x='if(lt(t,10),max(W-w*t,0),max(0-w*(t-10),0-W))'[bg] to your answer?
